# Prevent groovysh from stealing focus on macOS

Tags: groovyshell

When launching the Groovy REPL, `groovysh`, it also launches a separate support app that appears in the dock. This app thus steals focus meaning I can't start typing into the `groovysh` interpreter immediately; I need to click back to the terminal to get focus there again.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour or should I make a bug report? I found [this old ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/18750) which sounds promising but the focus theft persists.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
groovysh -Djava.awt.headless=true
```